# How to change values inside new Firebase onUpdate or onWrite triggers?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, triggers, google-cloud-functions

Before version (<= v0.9.1) it was possible to set data like that and now not anymore...

```
event.data.ref.child('thisname').set("error");
```

edit: setter are not mentioned here! Only how to receive values from onUpdate or onWrite
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Solution is posted below

Comment: Have a look at this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff. Syntax has indeed changed.

Comment: Sorry @RenaudTarnec i wanted to create the question and answer it straight away because i found the solution by myself...

Comment: You should not be sorry, no problem at all! Welcome on SO! :-)

Comment: ... Thanks man :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firebase**: *(supports version 1.0 or 2.0)*

If someone else has problems **changing** / **setting** / **updating** values in his cloud functions inside an onUpdate or onWrite trigger, then this might help u...

First this is how *my data tree* looks like:

```
"users" : {
    "4h23u45h23509hu346034h5943h5" : {
      "address" : "Backouse 2",
      "city" : "Los Angeles",
      "name" : "Joseph",
       ...
    },
    "23u4g24hg234h2ui342b34hi243n" : {
      "address" : "Streetouse 13",
      "city" : "Los Angeles",
      "name" : "Stefan",
      ...
```

Now to the cloud functions:

**Before (<= v0.9.1)**

```
exports.updatingUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
.onUpdate(event => {
  var address = event.data.child('address');
  var city = event.data.child('city');

  if (address.changed() || city.changed()) {
      //generateThisname()
      if (thisname == null) {
        event.data.ref.child('name').set("error");     //Important Part
      }
      else {
        event.data.ref.child('name').set(thisname);    //Important Part
      }
      ...
```

**Now (>= v1.0.0)**

```
exports.updatingUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  var addressBefore = change.before.child('address').val();
  var addressAfter = change.after.child('address').val();

  var cityBefore = change.before.child('city').val();
  var cityAfter = change.after.child('city').val();

  //create reference from root to users/{pushId}/
  var rootSnapshot = change.after.ref.parent.child(context.params.pushId)


      if ((addressBefore !== addressAfter) || (cityBefore !== cityAfter)) {
          //generateThisname()
          if (thisname === null) {
              rootSnapshot.child('name').set("error");
          }
          else {   
              rootSnapshot.child('name').set(thisname);
          }
          ...
```

So before you can set a value, you first have to make a reference from the root of your database and then go all the way down to you value and call set()

Comment: Since we are calling the set method, does this count as an additional write?